# Using Paginate with conditions and contain with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, pagination, conditional-statements, contain

So, I'ld like to paginate one of my request. The "normal way" didn't seems to work very well, so, I made a little research and all the answers ware telling to do something like this :

```
$this->paginate("Like",
    array("Like.user_id" => $id),
    array(
        "order" => "Like.created desc",
        "contain" => array(
            "User",
            "Post",
            "Post.User",
            "Post.Like"
        )
    )
);
```

The problem is that ... it doesn't work. A `debug` gives me something like that :

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Like' => array(
            'id' => '38',
            'created' => '2012-10-03 21:21:27',
            'post_id' => '29',
            'user_id' => '19'
        ),
        'Post' => array(
            'id' => '29',
            'title' => 'Don't Panic',
            'description' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam elementum sem ac sem imperdiet cursus. Quisque venenatis pulvinar ornare. Donec rutrum, lacus vel imperdiet sagittis, metus risus interdum ante, iaculis venenatis arcu nibh et odio.',
            'image' => '29-c49cb96c.jpg',
            'model' => '',
            'created' => '2012-09-07 01:46:49',
            'user_id' => '19',
            'project_id' => '1',
            'like_count' => '1'
        ),
        'User' => array(
            'password' => '*****',
            'id' => '19',
            'username' => 'Axiol'
        )
    )
)
```

No traces of `Post.User` and the `Post.Like`...

Any idea ?

EDIT:

Here are the models associations :

Post

```
public $belongsTo = array("User", "Project");
public $hasMany = array("Comment", "Like");
```

Like

```
public $belongsTo = array("User", "Post" => array("counterCache" => true));
```

User

```
public $hasMany = array("Post", "Comment");
```

Comment: "it doesn't work"? what do you mean?

Comment: As you can see in the debug, I don't have the sub-arrays `User` and `Like` under `Post`(différent from the others `Like` and `User` array)

Answer (score 2):

First off, you should indeed correct your `contain` array as Oldskool answered.

This should have been very obvious because cake throughs something like this:

```
Warning (512): Model "Post.Like" is not associated with model "Like" 
[CORE\Cake\Model\Behavior\ContainableBehavior.php, line 342]
```

You probably didn't see that because of your actual problem.

You fail to mention whether you are in any way loading the `Containable` behavior.
I'm assuming you aren't, and there you have it. The `contain` array is being ignored altogether.

[Here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) is the documentation for the `Containable` behavior.
My recommendation is that you add it to your `AppModel::actsAs` property like so:

```
class AppModel extends Model {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

This way, it is automatically available to all your models and you should stop using `recursive` madness too.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `Post.User` and `Post.Like` - those aren't models and shouldn't be listed in the `contain` array.

If they ARE model names - ie, you've specified the `$name` as such in your models (even though it breaks naming convention), then please post your models and their associations and we can look further.

Comment: Yes, they are model name. I edited my question with the associations.

Comment: @Axiol - Where are the associations for the `Post.User` and `Post.Like` models?

Answer (score 1):

As Dave already mentioned, your model names are off. You shouldn't use that notation, but rather include them as "nested" model underneath the one you're loading. Like this:

```
"contain" => array(
    "User",
    "Post" => array(
        "User", // Get post related user data
        "Like" // Get post related like data
    )
)
```